# React Native Linking Library

Tags: ios, react-native, static-linking

I wanted to use the Native IOS search bar from https://github.com/umhan35/react-native-search-bar and when I run npm install  --save (http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html) I get error bash: library-with-native-dependencies: No such file or directory. I tried to link the library manually but it fails without showing any error. Can some one help?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you did not type

```
npm install <library-with-native-dependencies> --save
-bash: library-with-native-dependencies: No such file or directory
```

In case you did, it should have been

```
npm install react-native-search-bar --save
```

If you managed to link it manually and run it, try setting a width and height for the SearchBar

```
 .........
 render(){
    return (<SearchBar style={styles.searchBar} ref='searchBar' placeholder='Search'/>);
 }
 .........
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  searchBar:{
    width: 200,
    height: 40
  }
 });
```

Comment: I tried manually linking is as well but it doesn't work. now I get the error Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'NativeModules.RNSearchBarManager.ComponentHeight'). I am sorry i am new to react native and get a lot of errors

Comment: hey thank you. I have linked it manually and using ramp and it was confused.I deleted the manually installed and run the commands again and it is working now

Comment: Welcome. Hope it is working now.  Was it the problem with incorrect linking ?

Comment: Yes. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

*Check whether module present in **ProjectDirectory -> node_modules -> react-native-search-bar***

*if Not Follow Below Steps*

*From Your Root Directory Open* ***package.json***

*Update your dependencies*

***Ex: Fetch from Github.***

```
"dependencies": { 
"react": "^0.14.8",
"react-native": "^0.25.1",
"react-native-search-bar": "git+https://github.com/umhan35/react-native-search-bar",
}
```

***OR***

***Ex: Fetch From NPM***

```
"dependencies": {
"react": "^0.14.8",
"react-native": "^0.25.1",
"react-native-search-bar": “^2.11.0",
}
```

*From Terminal Change to Your Project Directory.*

```
npm install
npm start
react-native run-ios
```

*Then you can just import this module wherever you want to use it.*

***Ex: In index.ios.js***

```
var awesomeSearchBar = require('react-native-search-bar’);
```